# How to programmatically assign a good width to a graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm generating a lot of faceted graphs with discrete x-axis inside my R scripts. Sometimes, I get overlapping labels in x-axis, and I would like to avoid it:

[image: ggsave overlaps]

Since I don't know in advance how big the graph is going to be (number of facets and breaks), I can't assign it manually to ggsave.

Any tips or best practices in this case?

Comment: Please give a reproducible example.

Comment: @agstudy your example is pretty good.

Comment: I noticed that when plotting (and viewing) graphs in RStudio, the labels are usually not overlapping. However, when I run the same scripts in the command line, I get the overlaps.

Comment: :) I avoided providing an example, because the question is not about one particular graph, but a general problem. If my line of thinking is wrong, I'll gladly provide an example the next time.

Comment: @agstudy thanks, will try to adhere to the best practice :)

Answer (score 2):

Not an exact solution but a practice that usually works well: You can **rotate** the axis labels.

```
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super",as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot") +
     facet_grid(~color)
library(gridExtra)

grid.arrange(q,
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)))
```

[image]

**second solution**

Use `facet_wrap` with one column ( 1 or few columns)

```
qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot") +
    facet_wrap(~color,ncol=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I was using the first approach with `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)))`, and it seems that rotation is the only way...

Comment: @NikolaKnezevic and what about the second method?

Comment: As I wrote in the post, I already use faceting, but some of my graphs have several columns (4).

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number of facets of your plot with the following function. I have tried to be as general as possible and it should be applicable for both `facet_grid` and `facet_wrap` faceting. It is however possible that I have overlooked some possibilities. If so, please leave a comment.

```
nfacetcols <- function(p) {
  if (is.null(p$facet$cols) & is.null(p$facet$facets)) return(1)
  # facet_grid - version
  if (! is.null(p$facet$cols)) {
    if (length(p$facet$cols)==0) return(1)
    dat <- p$data[,as.character(p$facet$cols)]
    if (is.factor(dat)) return(nlevels(dat)) 
    if (is.data.frame(dat)) return(nrow(unique(dat)))
    if (is.numeric(dat)) return(length(unique(dat)))
  }
  # facet_wrap - version
  if (! is.null(p$facet$facets)){
    if (!is.null(p$facet$ncol)) return(p$facet$ncol)
    dat <- p$data[,as.character(p$facet$facets)]
    tot <- ifelse(is.factor(dat), nlevels(dat), nrow(unique(dat)))
    if (!is.null(p$facet$nrow)) return(ceiling(tot/p$facet$nrow))
    return(ceiling(sqrt(tot)))
  }
}
```

With this function, you can extract the number of columns. The number of levels of your `x`-factor can easily be extracted using

```
xlvls <- nlevels(p$data[,p$labels$x])
```

Then using the suggestion of @agstudy, you can use the following code to `ggsave` your plot:

```
# create data set
set.seed(123)
N <- 20
df <- data.frame(a = sample(LETTERS[1:10], N, replace=TRUE), 
                 b = sample(letters[1:5], N, replace=TRUE), 
                 yax = rnorm(N), 
                 xax = factor(sample(letters[16:20], N, replace=TRUE)))
# plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(xax, yax)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(b~a) 
ggsave("eg.plot.png", 
       p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)), 
       width=xlvls*nfacetcols(p)/5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why is this better than just rotating the labels?

Comment: It isn't better. But your question stated "I don't know in advance how big the graph is going to be (number of facets and breaks)." This is just a way to find out. Perhaps that is also useful for other purposes than the saving, so I thought I would share...